# Where can I find videos of rock climbing competitions?

Tags: rock-climbing, bouldering, videography

I'm working on a school project where I'm trying to analyze rock climbing videos. Does anyone know where I can find a good source of rock climbing videos?

Ideally, I'm looking for videos with as little camera movement as possible with as few camera angle changes as possible. I've been looking at [USA Climbing's YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/USAClimbing) but was wondering if there are any better sources available – like unedited versions of the same competitions or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the official Youtube channel of the IFSC (International Federation of Sport Climbing) here. They cover all the official events.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2MGuhIaOP6YLpUx106kTQw

Comment: It may contain more view changes than the OP wants, but there's a lot of good video there.

Answer (score 3):

The British Mountaineering Council has a website and YouTube channel called "BMC TV". There are numerous instruction videos, interviews and clips of competitions.

https://www.thebmc.co.uk/articles/tag/bmc%20tv

https://www.youtube.com/teamBMCTV

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of a contrast to show you what comps looked like a few years back:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV7E64KGguY

A big contrast to contemporary comps here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26SOYIKPyOM

As a follow-up not to be super nit-picky but you mention 'I'm trying to analyze rock climbing videos'   yet you say you are looking for competition videos.  Usually comp videos are indoors and not on rock.  There are a few rock comps out there like hueco rock rodeo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QATvLHwwJE) and horseshoe hell.  I'm just curious if you are looking for both or strictly plastic.